# Tomcat randomly shutsdown

Tags: java, tomcat

I ran into a problem from couple weeks with my Tomcat. I deployed my webapp and it's been up and running for some time and one day it suddenly crashed.And I found that this happens when my tomcat server shutdown.

I started browsing Tomcat logs and found below 2 exception many times:

```
        23-Mar-2017 00:24:54.395 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
    Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character (CR or LF) found in method name
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:228)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        02-Apr-2017 23:43:36.006 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
    Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -64
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseHeader(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:474)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseHeaders(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:381)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1024)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

            https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59089
```

Does this error causes the tomcat to stop its service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character (CR or LF) found in method name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836379/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-character-cr-or-lf-found-in-method)

Comment: Have you tried another version of Tomcat? It's highly unusual that Tomcat crashes, cause of a 'bad' request...

Comment: @Ben No.But these are the only 2 exceptions that i got from tomcat catalina.out file.Does tomcat stops if some bad request comes many times??

Comment: What version of Tomcat do you use? There's a version which could be shutdown / crashed with a bad request..

Comment: @KJEjava48 No, not in my experiences. Try another tomcat version...Maybe you go out of memory? But this should be also in the log files

Comment: @Ben log files means catalina.out???Right??

Comment: @KJEjava48 It depends on your tomcat logging configuration (./conf/logging.properties), but I think catalina.out is the default.