# Error while running jsp file on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

This has become a serious issue for me. I'm getting the following error while I try to run my jsp file on eclipse.

```
Dec 27, 2017 11:51:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:235)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1045)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Following are the configurations on which I'm working on:
Machine : Mac
Tomcat version : I've tried with 9.0,8.5,8.0
Eclipse : Oxygen

I'm not even able to run a basic JSP file on Eclipse. I've tried changing many elements in server.xml and other properties files but in vain. 
But I could run the files from the browser when I copy them to the ROOT folder of the webapps directory of the installed tomcat. The same file I could not run from eclipse.

Could anyone please help me on this one?

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37836379/6505250

Comment: Actually I could able to run the jsp after placing it in the ROOT folder but I could only not run it in eclipse. And there is another point to mention over here that I've executed the same in Windows machine. But failed to run only in MAC. Please let me know in case I need to do any further configuration or anything else.

I've already configured SSL for Tomcat. Still in vain.