# port may already be in use or Invalid character found in method name

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I didn't change anything in my code (springboot applications). I have few projects but it doesn't matter which one I try to run I get one of these two errors. Also, It doesn't matter which port I choose, and chosen ports are not used by any other application at this time (checked by netstat).
But even if compiler says that port 8080 is used (it is port for http), application run correctly on 8443 on https.

I am not sure it is tied with my problem (I presume it is, but of course, it may be completely not related): recently I have installed VLC 3, VLC Setup Helper  and launched Lua HTTP interface. I unistalled both of them but it change nothing.

1.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:426) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

2.

```
Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8526 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8526, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Comment: Can you check what app/process is listening to port `8526`?

Comment: As I wrote, this port (and any other I tried) is not used by any other application. But maybe I checked it in wrong way?  
netstat -ona | findstr 8526  
I get empty result.  
  
When I run spring application I get:
netstat -ona | findstr 8526
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8526           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4916
  TCP    [::]:8526              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4916

Comment: You are checking for port use correctly. As a separate matter, is this answer to another SO post relevant?... [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character (CR or LF) found in method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836379/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-character-cr-or-lf-found-in-method/38999100#38999100)